# vscode c/c++ debugger not attaching UNRESPONSIVE extension host, 'ms-vscode.cpptools'

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Environment:

Ubuntu 18.04 ARM64

```
Version: 1.34.0 (vscode cloned from github) 
Commit: Unknown Date: Unknown 
Electron: 3.1.8 
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181 
Node.js: 10.2.0 
V8:6.6.346.32 
OS: Linux arm64 4.9.162-22
```

The only extensions I have installed are :
C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing.
Gitlens

In the json server log:

> Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9055/2f550349-85be-498d-ad48-8c3bb6ef8a40

In the Extension Host Log:

> ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.debug-server-ready
>   {"startup":false,"activationEvent":"onDebugResolve"}

In the Log Window:

```
[renderer1] [warning] UNRESPONSIVE extension host, 'ms-vscode.cpptools' took 90% of 636.705ms, saved PROFILE here: '/tmp/exthost-335d28.cpuprofile' [{"id":"ms-vscode.cpptools","total":574842,"percentage":90}]
[2019-04-13 09:46:42.608] [renderer1] [error] Unsupported client
[2019-04-13 09:47:01.556] [renderer1] [error] Unsupported client
.
.
.
```

Edit:

Reinstalled and found a broken dependency:

```
Updating C/C++ dependencies...

Downloading package 'Mono Framework Assemblies' (5368 KB)  Done!

Installing package 'Mono Framework Assemblies'
Failed at stage: installPackages
Error: end of central directory record signature not found
```

I'm not sure if this is a Linux package or some other js node?

I already have (linux) mono-complete and mono-runtime installed!

Comment: My problem turned out to be in the vscode-extension.  Vscode itself was alright!  Not sure why moderator changed tag otherwise.  I confirmed with vscode/cpptools git wiki that the extension simply doesn't support Aarch64 (arm64) architecture (yet).  A link is supplied here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/429.

Answer (score 2):

My problem turned out to be in the vscode-extension. Vscode itself was alright! I confirmed with vscode/cpptools git wiki that the extension simply doesn't support Aarch64 (arm64) architecture (yet). A link is supplied here [github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/429](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/429).